# google maps not loading in my android application

Tags: android

i have made an android application and in it , there is one scenario when the user clicks on an address and that address shows up on google maps. 
Now when i tested the application on the emulator, the google maps did load properly, but now that i am trying the same on my htc desire z, the maps is not loading.
Although the maps application which came built-in in my phone is loading google maps correctly.
what could be the problem? why is my application not able to load the map view?

thank you in advance.
EDIT: i have obtained a google map api key and have included it in the mapview that i am using.i have added overlays and etc. It is all showing fine on the emulator , but on my device it is not showing any maps. The overlays are visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between a debug maps API key and a release maps API key. With the first it will only run on the emulator.

Unless you have visited the Google site twice (once to get a key which matches the debug keystore and once to get a key which matches your release keystore) then you haven't got a release key and your app won't run on real device.

Comment: does it matter that i obtain the google api key from once account and upload the application on the android market via another account?

Comment: You must release the application with an API key that was derived from the MD5 fingerprint that was produced by your release key.

Answer (score 1):

Our Android developers were also facing this problem. We solved the problem like this:

1. We generated API keys from each machine and added the Key to their respective main.xml file. So each developer had a separate api key.
2. We started the emulator from the command line using the android "emulator" command which is located in the tools directory and started with the proxy option instead of starting it from eclipse, eg :

> E:>emulator -avd New_Device -http-proxy http://202.0.0.203:808

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you didn't register your application into the system. This is the link.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html

If this is not the case, please provide the error details from Logcat.

Comment: there is no error in the logcat. The maps are just not showing on my phone. On the emulator the maps are showing. and i did register, i obtained my map key from the site you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an API key from Google.

[Here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) is a good article that explain how to obtain API key.